# Telegram bot, sending message on start\open of app in python

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I have a Python script that works great with 'telegram bot'. I want to send the user a welcome message on start of the app.
Hopefuly someone here can direct me how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried using the send_text function in several places on the script with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, as the [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) does not send an update when the user opens the app.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. So is there any workaround or maybe to send a message on schedule?

Comment: The Bot API also doesn't include any scheduling functionality, you'll have to do that yourself.